# Basic: How do I get KendoUI widgets to render

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

I am trying to learn to use KendoUI.

I did a small tutorial and things seemed ok. As a next step I wanted to start implementing some of the demos. I started with the List View however I don't seem to be able to get it to render correctly.

I have put my attempt here:

- http://kendoui.herokuapp.com/listview

The demo and source code that I am trying to re-create are here:

- http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/index.html

Firebug shows that there are no javascript errors and all the CSS files seem to be referenced correctly so I can't understand why copying exactly the same code should have any problems.

If you have any ideas regarding what could be wrong, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Have to checked the assets required like images & css are in place.Bcz the image looks from shared CDN network.If possible can you post what error/diffrence you are getting with firebug response.

Comment: The problem is that firebug doesn't show any errors. The images that are in /public/... are actually local. I am using PlayFramework as the MVC framework (with Java) and all static resources go in /public/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the CSS stylesheet for mobile: kendo.mobile.all.min.css